# Grep regex to select only 10 character

Tags: regex, grep

I have a log file that I'm grep(ing) to select certain character.

The pattern of the log file looks like this

```
Some Random string.... Message Sent [10 character --
```

What I'm interested in only the 10 character string present between *[* and *--*

I have successfully managed to compose the regex that look like this

```
"Message Sent \[.\{10\} --"
```

I have cross checked the above regex over [here](https://rubular.com/r/i8QdSErtGo).

But unfortunately the regex does not yield any output

```
grep -o "Message Sent \[.\{10\}) --" log/development.log
```

But I'm mostly interested in the 10 character but the above regex yield `'Message Sent ['` + `10 character` + `--`

Any Clue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\K` (*pattern from Perl-regex*) to discard the previously matched chars.

```
grep -oP 'Message Sent \[\K.{10}(?= -+)' log/development.log
```

or

```
grep -oP 'Message\s+Sent\s+\[\K.{10}(?=\s+-+)' log/development.log
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eS8jW3/5)

Comment: do you a link for `\K` definition.

Comment: Awesome Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sed:

```
$ sed -r -n 's/.*Message Sent \[(.{10}).*/\1/p' file
10 charact
```