# awk: fatal: Invalid regular expression when setting multiple field separators

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I was trying to solve [Grep regex to select only 10 character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36785859/1983854) using `awk`. The question consists in a string `XXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZZ` and the OP wants to print the text in between the unique `[` and `--` strings within the text.

If it was just one `-` I would say use `[-[]` as [field separator](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_23.html) (FS). This is setting the FS to be either `-` or `[`:

```
$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY-ZZZZ" | awk -F[-[] '{print $2}'
YYYYY
```

The tricky point is that `[` has also a special meaning as a character class, so that to make it be correctly interpreted as one of the possible FS it cannot be written in the first position. Well, this is done by saying `[-[]`. So we are done to match either `-` or `[`.

However, in this case it is not one but two hyphens: I want to say either `--` or `[`. I cannot say `[--[]` because the hyphen also has a meaning to define a range.

What I can do is to use `-F"one pattern|another pattern"` like:

```
$ echo "XXXXXXXaaYYYYYbbZZZZ" | awk -F"aa|bb" '{print $2}'
YYYYY
```

So if I try to use this with `--` and `[`, I cannot get a proper result:

```
$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk -F"--|[" '{print $2}'
awk: fatal: Invalid regular expression: /--|[/
```

And in fact, not even having `[` as one of the terms:

```
$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYYbbZZZZ" | awk -F"bb|[" '{print $2}'
awk: fatal: Invalid regular expression: /bb|[/

$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYYbbZZZZ" | awk -F"bb|\[" '{print $2}'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
awk: fatal: Invalid regular expression: /bb|[/

$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYYbbZZZZ" | awk -F"(bb|\[)" '{print $2}'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
awk: fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /(bb|[)/
```

You see I tried to either escaping `[`, enclosing in parentheses and nothing worked.

So: what can I do to set the field separator to either `--` or `[`? Is it possible at all?

Comment: use \\ , `awk -F"(bb|\\[)" '{print $2}' a` or `awk -v FS="bb|\\[" '{print $2}' a`

Comment: and ans for him `echo 'Message Sent [M0AO40PXPW --' | awk -v FS="\\[| " '{print $4}'`

Comment: or `echo 'Message Sent [M0AO40PXPW --' | awk -v FS="\\[| +--" '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO this is best explained if we start by looking at a regexp being used by the split() command since that explicitly shows what is happening when a string is split into fields using a literal vs dynamic regexp and then we can relate that to Field Separators.

This uses a literal regexp (delimited by `/`s):

```
$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk '{split($0,f,/\[|--/); print f[2]}'
YYYYY
```

and so requires the `[` to be escaped so it is taken literally since `[` is a regexp metacharacter.

These use a dynamic regexp (one stored as a string):

```
$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk '{split($0,f,"\\[|--"); print f[2]}'
YYYYY

$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk 'BEGIN{re="\\[|--"} {split($0,f,re); print f[2]}'
YYYYY

$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk -v re='\\[|--' '{split($0,f,re); print f[2]}'
YYYYY
```

and so require the `[` to be escaped 2 times since awk has to convert the string holding the regexp (a variable named `re` in the last 2 examples) to a regexp (which uses up one backslash) before it's used as the separator in the split() call (which uses up the second backslash).

This:

```
$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk -v re="\\\[|--" '{split($0,f,re); print f[2]}'
YYYYY
```

exposes the variable contents to the shell for it's evaluation and so requires the `[` to be escaped 3 times since the shell parses the string first to try to expand shell variables etc. (which uses up one backslash) and then awk has to convert the string holding the regexp to a regexp (which uses up a second backslash) before it's used as the separator in the split() call (which uses up the third backslash).

A Field Separator is just a regexp stored as variable named FS (like `re` above) with some extra semantics so all of the above applies to it to, hence:

```
$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk -F '\\[|--' '{print $2}'
YYYYY

$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk -F "\\\[|--" '{print $2}'
YYYYY
```

Note that we could have used a bracket expression instead of escaping it to have the `[` treated literally:

```
$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk '{split($0,f,/[[]|--/); print f[2]}'
YYYYY
```

and then we don't have to worry about escaping the escapes as we add layers of parsing:

```
$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk -F "[[]|--" '{print $2}'
YYYYY

$ echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk -F '[[]|--' '{print $2}'
YYYYY
```

Comment: Wow! That's a real canonical answer, mister Ed Morton. Big thanks for your never ending effort in making `awk` greater and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double backslash for escaping regex meta  chars inside double quoted string so that it would be treated as regex meta character otherwise (*if you use single backslash*) it would be treated as ecape sequence.

```
$ echo 'XXXXXXX[YYYYYbbZZZZ' | awk -v FS="bb|\\[" '{print $2}'
YYYYY
```

Comment: What version of awk are you using? With my `GNU Awk 4.0.1` I get a two lines error --> `awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
awk: fatal: Invalid regular expression: /bb|[/`.

Comment: @fedorqui This is the right regex, but FS needs to be in single quotes, otherwise one of the two backslashes is swallowed by bash `echo 'XXXXXXX[YYYYYbbZZZZ' | awk -v FS='bb|\\[' '{print $2}'`

Comment: @user000001 oh, I see! To have it work with double quotes you have to quadruple-escape it `-v FS="bb|\\\\["`. Also, it is funny `-v FS='bb|\\['` works but `-F'bb|\['` does not.

Comment: @fedorqui: It fails on gawk, but it seems to work in mawk. I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801373/pipe-symbol-in-awk-field-delimiter/34802133#34802133. The reason GNU awk doesn't like the syntax is that is parses the FS two times: one as a string literal, and one as a regex

Comment: @user000001 wow, this is getting bigger. In my GNU awk `echo 'XXXXXXX[YYYYYbbZZZZ' | awk -F'bb\|\\[' '{print $2}'` returns `YYYYY` together with a warning `awk: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'`.

Comment: @EdMorton then I don't understand how `echo 'XXXXXXX[YYYYYbbZZZZ' | awk -F'bb\|\\[' '{print $2}'` returns `YYYYY` if `|` is treated literally. If it is, my guess is that the `FS` would be the full string `bb|[`, while it interprets (I think) either `bb` or `[`. Would you mind posting an answer with the details for future reference?

Comment: @fedorqui OK, I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This with GNU Awk 3.1.7

```
echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYY--ZZZZ" | awk -F"--|[[]" '{print $2}'    
echo "XXXXXXX[YYYYYbbZZZZ" | awk -F"bb|[[]" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: This worked very well! Mind to explain why? It looks like saying `[[]` instead of `[` alone made it.

Comment: I don't have clear idea. I guess it is because we use `[]` regex to match single character so awk expects you to close `[` with `]`. Thus error.

Comment: Explanation: `[` is a regexp metacharacter. If you want it, or any other regexp metacharacter, to be treated literally then you need to enclose it in a bracket expression `[<char>]` or escape it `\<char>`.