# Split and compare in awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to split and comparison in awk command.

Input file (tab-delimited)

```
1 aaa 1|3
2 bbb 3|3
3 ccc 0|2
```

Filtration

1. First column value > 1
2. First value of third column value splitted by "|" > 2

Process

1. Compare first column value if bigger than 1
2. Split third column value by "|"
3. Compare first value of the third column if bigger than 2
4. Print if the first value bigger than 2 only

Command line (example)

```
awk -F "\t" '{if($1>1 && ....?) print}' file
```

Output

```
2 bbb 3|3
```

Please let me know command line for above processing.

Comment: tr '|' ' ' < FileName.txt |awk '$1 >1 && $4>2  {print}'

Comment: add some clarity in question if this does not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the field separator to either tab or pipe and check the 1st and 3rd values:

```
awk -F'\t|\\|' '$1>1 && $3>2' file
```

or

```
awk -F"\t|\\\\|" '$1>1 && $3>2' file
```

You can read about all this character escaping in this comprehensive answer by Ed Morton in [awk: fatal: Invalid regular expression when setting multiple field separators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36806066/1983854).

Otherwise, you can split the 3rd field and check the value of the first slice:

```
awk -F"\t" '{split($3,a,"|")} $1>1 && a[1]>=2' file
```

Comment: Working well. Thank you very much. And thanks for very useful link too.